# Trying to check user credentials from two different mySQL tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to check login credentials against 2 different tables and the query keeps coming back saying that the user doesn't exist. I will try to explain what I am doing...

I have a table called `customers` that stores customer data only. I have another table called `admins` that stores credentials for admins only.

I would like to have the admins be able to log in to the site using the same log in screen as the customers. Once they are logged in, the system will know that they are an admin and display the proper widgets for administrating the product data on the site.

I inserted a dummy user in the `admins` table and ran this query:

```
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM `customers` WHERE `email` = 'johndeere@whatever.com' AND `password` = 'password'
    UNION
    SELECT 1 FROM `admins` WHERE `Email` = 'johndeere@whatever.com' AND `Password` = 'password'
    )");
    $result = @mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$result) {
        echo "User doesn't exist!";
    } else {
        echo "User exists!";
    }
```

This query is coming back saying "User doesn't exist" when I know for a fact they are in the `admins` table. I'm sure that I am missing something very simple and was hoping someone could help me out with what it is.

I am still pretty new to mySQL and PHP but I am learning fast. This is, so far, the only problem that I could not fix or find an answer for. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you use,

```
SELECT 1 from dual where EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM `customers` WHERE `email` = 'johndeere@whatever.com' AND `password` = 'password'
    UNION
    SELECT 1 FROM `admins` WHERE `Email` = 'johndeere@whatever.com' AND `Password` = 'password'
);
```

your query will return 0(false), 1(true), you need to check these values, if you use original query

You can't use `!$result` as it only tells weather query was legal or not., you need to retrieve the data.

Refer this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: I ran that query and it came back as "User exists!" but when I purposely put the wrong password in the query, it also said the user exists. $sql = mysql_query("SELECT 1 from dual where EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM `customers` WHERE `email` = 'johndeere@whatever.com' AND `hello` = 'password'
    UNION
    SELECT 1 FROM `admins` WHERE `Email` = 'johndeere@whatever.com' AND `hello` = 'password'
)");
$result = @mysql_query($sql);
if($result === 0) {
    echo "User doesn't exist!";
} else {
    echo "User exists!";
}

Comment: i don't know php, but i think you you can use this:`if($result === 1) { echo "User exist!"; } else { echo "User doesn't  exists!";`

Comment: The query seems to be coming back true no matter what conditions I put in to look for. I can put any email address and any password in the query and it comes back true no matter what.

Comment: i was just reading php, you can't access data by just using result, you need to retrive the result use `if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) { echo "User exist!"; } else { echo "User doesn't exists!";}`

Comment: and also use should use a sql client like sqlyog or online tool like http://sqlfiddle.com/([demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08a0d/12)), so that you can learn mysql

Comment: I think I have the query correct but, when I try to output the result to the screen, I get "mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given" the output code looks like this: `$result = @mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
    echo "User exists!";
} else {
    echo "User doesn't exist!";
}`